# numpy fill_between() different diagonal values

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have created a 3x3 np.array full of zeros with `a = np.zeros((3,3))`.
I have another 3x1 numpy array `b = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])` which values I want to set for the diagonal values in a. Hence I as result I want to have a matrix with the values of b on the diagonal and zeros everywhere else. 
I tried using the [np.fill_diagonal()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html) function with the following code:

```
a = np.zeros((3,3))
b = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
print(np.fill_diagonal(a,b))
```

As result I get:

> None

What I am doing wrong and how can I accomplish the above?

Comment: Tried `c = np.fill_diagonal(a,b)`

`print(c)` as well as simply `np.fill_diagonal(a,b)` but didn't work at all

Comment: As written, I tried it but it didnt't work at all.

Comment: Simply `np.fill_diagonal(a,b)` but this led to a *None* as well

Comment: No I didn't thanks a lot! Please post it as an answer

Comment: you could also multiply your vector by the identity matrix instead of filling a zero matrix, e.g. `a = np.identity(3); b = np.arange(1,4); a * b` to get the same result